# How to see StoryBoard View in 3.5 and 4 inches in XCode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

In Xcode 5 there was an option which let us see the View how it will look in 3.5inches and 4 inches screen.

[image]

as highlighted in the red circle. i can't find this option in Xcode 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist of all you select View Controller than click on `attributes inspector` `size` field is show select your size see below

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dheeraj Kumar :)

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust your `storyboard` size like `320X480` `3.5 inches` and `320*568 4 inches`.

Click view controller change your simulated size just change freeform and give width and height size .

Answer (score 1):

I also new in `Xcode 6` and I also faced this problem , now I identify my self `Storyboard in different views` using the following method.

goto attribute inspector - size - select  your screen size is inferred  to `iPhone 3.5` or ....